# Navbar active page

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have this one problem regarding the highlighted navbar menu which will only highlight when we clicked on it. For that to work, I'm using javascript. However, each pages has its own sub pages, for example, page Home has a link of local/home, but its content will lead to local/home/content. The sub link will not make the navbar to function The navbar was coded in different file, which I just extends in the home and other pages. I'm not very good at explaining but if I can elaborate more on any part I would do so. Below I attached my JS and my navbar:

Navbar :

```
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="{{ url('/') }}">Home
                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('courses') }}">opportunities</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('events') }}">events</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('uqalc') }}">courses</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('contact') }}">contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Javascript :

```
const currloc = location.href;
        const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('a');
        const menuLen = menuItem.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < menuLen; i++) {
            menuItem[i].classList.remove('active');
            if (menuItem[i].href === currloc) {
                menuItem[i].className = "nav-link active";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do the href of the links match the url when navigated to them? I mean are you redirecting the user when opening the link?

Comment: No, it does not. Thats because it changes on web.php, the route. Im using Laravel framework.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I add active class to the anchor tag which is inside `.navbar-nav` If the window location is `https://www.google.com/index.html`

then this code find an anchor tag which one inside the `.navbar-nav` if anchor tag href should be `index.html` then this code add class `active` to the anchor tag

```
    function removeQueryString(url) {
        return url.split('?')[0]
    }
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-nav a'), function(elem) {
        if (removeQueryString(elem.href) === removeQueryString(window.location.href))
        elem.classList.add('active')
        else
        elem.classList.remove('active')
    })
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I tried it, and the result seems just as mine previously. Or do I need to add anything else?

Comment: What is page type HTML or PHP? I mean index.php or index.html

Comment: function myFunction(e) {
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll("a");
            [].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
                el.classList.remove("active");
            });
            e.target.className = "nav-link active";
        }

I tried this one, it works for subpages, but not working for other navbar.

Comment: Can You please share your site live link so I can check

Comment: Link : http://yutp-uqal.com/home-events
Under it there's like 2 card. If I click "Detail", it will still reload same page, just that the link changes its path to different content. And that's where the navbar starts to not work.

Comment: Hello there. Do you think its possible or do I have to restructure it?